# Possible to automatically display the correct days of the week?

Tags: conky

I'd like to tweak my Conky so it automatically displays the days of the week correctly. So for example, if TODAY were Tuesday, it would look like this:

Tuesday

Wednesday

Thursday

Friday

[etc.]

And then tomorrow, *automatically*, it would look like this:

Wednesday

Thursday

Friday

[etc.]

I know I can get it to display *today's* date like this:

${time %A}

But how do I get it to display tomorrow's date?

Thanks so much for any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **$execi** Conky command to make what you want.

This command executes a shell command with specific interval and displays the output in conky.

For your need, you can execute the standard date command :

```
date -d tomorrow
```

This will return the tomorrow date using the standard output, but you can specify your output format using date parameters (see man date)

So what you need to enter in your .conkyrc script is :

```
${execi 3600 date -d tomorrow}
```

The interval is in seconds, I set it to 3600 but change it with your ideal interval

Comment: I'm wondering if it's possible to use the same command for time? I'm asking because currently I have ${time %I:%M %p}  ${font sans:style=bold:size=24}${color orange}6:30 PM appointment and it'd be great to have something that tells me how long I have until my appointment happens. (Apologies for the one long paragraph. I'm still really struggling with how to format.)